# How to move images slightly up on scroll using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple parallax effect using Jquery (without plugins). Basically I have a few different images layered on-top of each-other and need them to move slightly upwards at different speeds when a user scrolls down, similar to a parallax scrolling effect.

Here's the layout so far (excuse the sloppy code):

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ededed;
    z-index: 4;
    display: table;
    
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffde15;
    height: 900px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
}
.headertopimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
.headerbehindimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    top:0%;

}
.headerbehindbehindimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 8;
    margin-top: 8%;
    

}
.headerbgimg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    z-index: 7;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -35%;

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="headertop"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/z2DORfA.png" class="headertopimg"> </div>
    <div class="headerbehind"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/o1Yl0PD.png" class="headerbehindimg"></div>
    <div class="headerbehindbehind"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/VQxs9LD.png" class="headerbehindbehindimg"></div>
    <div class="headerbg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/t5fTRZe.png" class="headerbgimg"></div>
    
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need the jquery?  Use a `.scroll()` handler. http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: Why not use google first? There's plenty of simple tutorials that you can find e.g. by googling "parallax pure javascript". And by simple I mean very simple, the piece of code that you need for a basic parallax effect is just a few lines.

Comment: @Roope Thanks, that search gave some good results